# Debug stm32 nucleo using gdb

Tags: c, gdb, stm32

how can I debug STM32 board using **gdb** without *stlink* or any other device.
actually I am trying to design an equipment which can replace the STMC device, since ST was stopped making this devices

Comment: Check OpenOCD out. But STLink has its own proprietary gdb server I believe.

Comment: With the Cortex-M ones it's impossible; OpenOCD and all other GDB servers require some additional hardware (debug adapter) - you always need something to connect to the SWD/JTAG port. The STM32MP1 ones can run Linux, so you can run gdb on applications there as usual, perhaps via SSH, but you still need some cables for that (Ethernet or USB).

Comment: @Erlkoenig Oh... Looks like I read "without stlink" as "with stlink"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot debug a bare metal system without a debugger.  STM32 support JTAG, SWD debuggers. You still can program it without a programmer/debugger (using the integrated bootloader if present in your model) and put your debug string on an uart, but no conventional debuggin, so no gdb.